# information and rational fractions

Tags: elementary-number-theory, information-theory, rational-numbers

I am confused about the information content of exact decimal representations of rational fractions (a whole number divided by another whole number). Some, such as ¼ are finite (0.25), some, infinite 1/3 =0.33333…The example: 93/104, has a lead in of 3 digits then an infinitely repeated sequence of 6 digits: 0.894[230769] [230769] ….; while 93/108 = 0.86[1][1]….; Division by a prime number has no lead in, only an infinitely repeated sequence eg for 93/107 the sequence is 53 digits, while 93/113  has a 112 digit sequence, (which is the maximum possible length of the repeat sequence  = denominator -1). It seems different amounts of information are required to exactly specify each of these apparently similar fractions. Is this so? or do they have the same information content but some are more “compressible”, contrasting with irrational fractions which are not “compressible” at all?

Comment: Base $10$ notation is more convenient for some fractions than it is for others.  $\frac 17$ is terminating in base $7$, for example.

Comment: For fractions whose denominators $m$ are coprime with $10$, the length of the period is the order of $10 \bmod m$, a chaotic function of $m$.

Comment: And for fractions whose demoninators are not coprime with $10$, you can multiply them by $10^n$ to get a fraction with a denominator coprime with $10$. That multiplication just moves the decimal point in the representation, so the repeating sequence is unchanged. Thus the length of the period can always be obtained from the order of $10 \bmod m$, where $m$ is the denominator of the reduced fraction with all factors of $2$ and $5$ removed from it.

Comment: Interesting points but i still dont know if 93/108 and 93/107 require different amounts of information to specify them exactly (the first having only 3 decimal digits and the second 53 decimal digits...). Or does the concept of the absolute information content of these fractions make no sense?

Comment: $108 = 2^2 3^3$ and the order of $10 \bmod 3^3$ is $3$, whereas the order of $10 \bmod 107$ is $53$.